# How to clear an input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have 3 inputs:

```
<label for="text1">Text 1</label>
<input type="text" class="text1" value="To clear"><br>

<label for="text2">Text 2</label>
<input type="text" class="text2" value="to select"><br>

<label for="text3">Text 3</label>
<input type="text" class="text3" value="Click in this field">
```

I would like that when you click in the text3, it erases the text1.
I did a function but it does not work:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(text3) {
        document.text1.value = "";
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: Well, when is `myFunction` called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to assign an event listener to the element, within that you can call your function

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector('input.text1').value = "";
}


document.querySelector('input.text3').addEventListener('focus', myFunction);
```

```html
<label for="text1">Text 1</label>
<input type="text" class="text1" value="To clear"><br>

<label for="text2">Text 2</label>
<input type="text" class="text2" value="to select"><br>

<label for="text3">Text 3</label>
<input type="text" class="text3" value="Click in this field">
```

Make sure to select your elements with DOM methods like `querySelector`, `getElement(s)By...` and so on. Never rely on accessing an element by it's global id as this may break depending on used browser. (Though `document.text1.value = "";` will never work..)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text1 = document.querySelector('.text1');
var text3 = document.querySelector('.text3');

text3.addEventListener('focus', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  text1.value = '';
}
```

```html
<label for="text1">Text 1</label>
<input type="text" class="text1" value="To clear"><br>

<label for="text2">Text 2</label>
<input type="text" class="text2" value="to select"><br>

<label for="text3">Text 3</label>
<input type="text" class="text3" value="Click in this field">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily using JQuery .

```js
    $('.text3').on('focus', function() {
      $('.text1').val('');
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <label for="text1">Text 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="text1" value="To clear"><br>

    <label for="text2">Text 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="text2" value="to select"><br>

    <label for="text3">Text 3</label>
    <input type="text" class="text3" value="Click in this field">
```